# App crashes frequently at time when UIActionSheet would be presented

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

I am getting the following error intermittently when a call is made to display an action sheet.

> Assertion failure in -[UIActionSheet showInView:]
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: view != nil'

Now in this case I've not changed screens.  The UIActionSheet is presented when a local notification is fired and I have an observer call a local method on this view as such: I have the property marked as strong.  When the action sheet is dismissed I also set it to nil.  I am using a story board for the UI.  It's fairly repeatable to crash it, perhaps less than 5 tries.  (Thankfully I have that going for me).  Any suggestions what to try next? I'm really pulling my hair out on this one.  Most of the issues I've seen on this topic are pointing to the crash occurring once the selection is made. In my case it's at presentation and intermittently.  Also for what it's worth, this particular view is several stacks deep in an embedded navigation controller.  Home>tableview>detail select>viewController in question.  This same issue occurs so far in testing on iOS 5.1 and iOS 6.  I'm presuming it's something to do with how the show InView is being targeted.

```
self.actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                            initWithTitle:@"Select Choice" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Not Yet" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Do this Now" otherButtonTitles:nil];

[self.actionSheet showInView:self.parentViewController.tabBarController.view];
```

Comment: The `UIActionSheet` code you provided does not coincide with the crash you posted. You are using **`showFromTabBar `** where as the crash is stating you are using **`showInView`**.

Comment: You are correct, I have updated so it matches. I also tried the previous which also crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, it would seem that `self.tabBarController` or `self.tabBarController.tabBar` are not set when this is called.

Try using:

```
[self.actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

**Edit:** fixed error

**Edit 2:** Making the action sheet appear on top of a tab bar

```
[self.actionSheet showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window]];
```

Comment: This gives me a compiler warning of incompatible pointer types sending Uiview * to a parameter of type UITabBar *

Comment: @JimHankins Excuse me for making that mistake, it has been corrected.

Comment: So actually that is what I previously had but this creates a problem with the clickable area for the bottom button. That is how I got to this point. The above will work by not crashing but isn't correct due to the tabBar being present.

Comment: @JimHankins Updated again, try that.

Comment: So that seems to have solved for the crash issue and the touch area is correct but now each successive time I call this in this way, I get N+1 number of ActionSheets displayed. I've tried setting the self.actionsheet.delegate to nil and self.actionsheet to nil on the clicked button at index method. That didn't work, also in the viewDidDisappear (because I pop the view in between attempts).  Still duplicates the action sheet.

Comment: Could you post (in your original question) the code you are using including lines which provide context to what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the problem was that I was not removing an NSNotificationCenter observer.  It only became obvious when the change was made recommended by @zsnow which resolved the crash but resulted in duplicated UIAlertSheet dialogs being presented.

In my particular case adding the following resolved my issue.  Thanks for everyone's help. The suggestions got me close enough to cross the finish line.

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

}